# Mock internal method of a class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

```
public Employe{
   public Double method1(int id){
      return method2(id);
   }
   public Double method2(int id) throws DatabaseException{
      //Some Code
      Employe e = employeRepositoy.getEmployeWithId(id);
      return e.getSalary();
   }
}
```

Now my two test scenarios are like this

```
@Test(expected = DatabaseException.class)
public void testemploye1() throws ServiceException, DatabaseException {
    Employe employe = Mockito.spy(new Employe());
    when(employe.method2(45585)).thenThrow(DatabaseException.class);
    employe .method1(45585);
}

@Test
public void testEmployee() throws ServiceException, DatabaseException {
    Employe employe = Mockito.spy(new Employe());
    when(employe.method2(45585)).thenReturn(3256);
    Double sal = employe .method1(45585);
    isTrue(sal.equals(3256));
}
```

First test scenerio runs fines and throws database exception. But in the second test scenrio instead of mocking the call goes into the internal method2 and throws null pointer exception. I am kind of suck here any help in this regard.

Comment: You should not mock the *class under test* itself. This is a sign that the *Single responsibility Pattern* is violated. - To you problem: try the `doReturn(xxx).when(mockOrSpy).method()` form which does not call the mocked method.

Answer (score 2):

The NPE is occurring because `employeRepositoy` is null. Are you **sure** that `testemploye1()` is passing? As far as I can see it will fail with the same NPE, perhaps if you peek inside the actual exception cause you might see that `testemploye1()` is throwing a NPE too.

I think the testing approach is slightly 'off', if the intention is to test the behaviour of method2 (whether called directly or called via method1()) then I think you should be mocking `employeRepositoy` and injecting this and then providing it with expected behaviour. For example:

```
@Test(expected = DatabaseException.class)
public void testemploye1() {
  EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = Mockito.mock(EmployeeRepository.class);

  Employe employe = new Employe(employeeRepository);

  int id = 12345;
  when(employeeRepository.getEmployeWithId(id)).thenThrow(new DatabaseException());
  employe.method1(id);
}

@Test
public void testEmployee() {
  EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = Mockito.mock(EmployeeRepository.class);

  Employe employe = new Employe(employeeRepository);

  int id = 12345;
  Employe storedEmploye = ...;
  when(employeeRepository.getEmployeWithId(id)).thenReturn(storedEmploye);
  Double salary = employe.method2(id);
  assertEquals(storedEmploye.getSalary(), salary);
}
```

However, as other posters have noted this test approach does look rather odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think for Spy's you need to use the following syntax for stubbing methods:

```
doReturn(100).when(employe).method2(45585);
```

instead of:

```
when(employe.method2(45585)).thenReturn(3256);
```

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to use when(Object) for stubbing [spies.](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

```
@Test
public void testEmployee() throws ServiceException, DatabaseException {
  Employe employe = Mockito.spy(new Employe());
  doReturn(3256).when(employe).method2(45585);    
  //when(employe.method2(45585)).thenReturn(3256);
  Double sal = employe .method1(45585);
  isTrue(sal.equals(3256));
}
```